# Identifying HP Printers with NMAP and then using results in Python/Perl

Tags: nmap, python, perl, printers

Great write up on network printer hacking at IronGeek's site here for anyone interested http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/networkprinterhacking.

Here's what I want to do: 
Scan the subnet for HP printers with port 9100 open. I know I can use OS fingerprinting and the port argument to filter it down. I want to export the IP addresses matching this criteria to a file or list, and then telnet to every one of those IPs and issue a command. Specifically: @PJL RDYMSG DISPLAY=”YOUR MESSAGE“. This will cause the printers to display a custom ready message.

Advice? Guidance? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality already exists in Nmap, in the [`pjl-ready-message`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/pjl-ready-message.html) NSE script. Here's an example usage:

```
nmap -p 9100 --script pjl-ready-message --script-args pjl_ready_message="your message here" 192.0.2.0/24
```

The script already checks for a real PJL service before sending the command, so you probably don't have to check for OS fingerprint results.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this could be facilitated by using [NSE](http://nmap.org/book/nse.html).
Take for instance the following script (called **hp.nse**):

```
function portrule(host, port)
  if port.state == "open" then
    cmd = "echo " .. host.ip .. " >> targets.txt"
    os.execute(cmd)
  end
end

function hostrule(host)
end

function action()
end
```

If you run:

```
nmap -p 9100 -n --script=./hp.nse 192.168.1.*
```

Assuming that your network is 192.168.1.0/24, it will match every host that's online with port 9100 open. For every host that matches these rules, this script will echo its address to the **targets.txt** file. From there, you can adapt IronGeek's scripts to read from **targets.txt** and issue the respective telnet commands. Something like:

```
my $filename = "targets.txt";
open my $handle, $filename or die;
while(my $ip = <$handle>)  {   
    print $ip;
    # Declare socket for $ip.
    # Echo HP commands to that socket.
}
close $handle;
```

About the OS detection, I believe it will require more work to match the OS string with regular expressions (and risking missing a real HP printer) than if you simply try and send the HP commands to every host with port 9100 open. If you want to give it a try, here's the [NSE's API](http://nmap.org/book/nse-api.html).